# Trying to put text and links into a header

Tags: custom-header

I am trying to add some items to a header. I want to put some text in the center and I would like to add social media icons and links.

I have no programming expertise, so type slowly and in short words so I can understand. I might be asking for something that I am t of my league on, but I am hoping to save a couple bucks.

The website is [jonathanthedroneguy.com](http://jonathanthedroneguy.com).

It's a narrow header, but I want to add 3 lines of text in the center of the header and social media icons to the right of the menu.

Comment: Well, you'll have to edit the code in your header.php file most likely. If you have no experience, it's probably worth buying an hour of time from a developer to help you. It shouldn't take long.

Comment: Bob, there's a bit of work that would be involved as you're going to have to consider what happens when the site is viewed on tablets and mobiles as well. If you're looking to save a couple of bucks though, just dive in!  Try a few things and see what happens (on a development version of your site of course).  Von was right that a good starting place would be your header.php.

Comment: In general, you want to edit the file header.php that located in wp-content/themes. About the elements you want to add and their position, you need some knowledge in CSS.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I had a feeling, but thought maybe there would be some kind of a plugin or a trick that would make it easier. Seems like everything else is so simple to change, the header should be easy, but... All good! Thanks.